# Probability of 100 numbers to be generated in certain order

Tags: probability

What's the probability of 100 randomly generated numbers to be arranged in certain order? For example 0 to 9 for 10 times, or for more than 100 numbers these numbers to be generated with the following order 0 to 99.

Comment: Which random numbers do we generate ? From $0$ to $99$ ? Please formulate more clearly!

Comment: Let's say we have an array with 100 boxes and each box can get the values from 0 to 99. What's the probability that these boxes are sorted when I randomly put values to them. Each value can appear only 1 time (but I would also like to know the probability if each value can appear more than 1 times). Sorry for not clarifying it on the original question!

Comment: Well, there are $100!$ equally probable permutations and only one of them is "in order" so your answer would be $\frac 1{100!}$, if I have understood the question (not clear).

Comment: If the values are distinct, we have $100!\approx 9.3\cdot 10^{157}$ possible outcomes and only in $1$ case, the boxes have the right order. So, the probability is about $10^{-158}$.If we allow duplicates, we have $100^{100}=10^{200}$ possible outcomes, so the probability is $10^{-200}$, so even smaller. @lulu seems that this is meant

Comment: Thanks both of you, that helped a lot!

Comment: If one number is allowed to be generated many times there is not only one permutation which is acceptable to get the right order any longer. For example in the sequence $1,2,2,3,4,5$ we can switch place of the $2$s and it will still be sorted.